# Getting error when generating an unlocked package version using a scratch org definition file

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, unlocked-package

I am currently generating a package version using CLI and I am using this following definition file:

```
{
  "orgName": "scratch-org",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": [
    "ContactsToMultipleAccounts",
    "MultiCurrency",
    "Communities"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "enhancedNotesSettings": {
      "enableEnhancedNotes": true
    }
  },
  "language": "en_US",
  "hasSampleData": false
}
```

but the error below I get has to do with User Interface Settings but I have not defined anything related to it.

```
ERROR running force:package:version:create:  
UserInterface: Error parsing file: Element {}enableCollapsibleSidebar invalid at this location in type UserInterfaceSettings
```

Am I missing something here or is it a bug from the CLI?

Comment: By "I have not defined anything related to it" I assume you mean you **don't** have any metadata that includes the text "{}enableCollapsibleSidebar" in your source structure?

Comment: do you have `settings` folder in your UnlockedPackage folder?

Comment: No the metadata is not being verified at that stage and no I do not have `settings` folder

Comment: Did you search your whole source structure for the offending value?

Comment: yes I just did I am sure I do not have anything related to "enableCollapsibleSidebar" it has happened in many packages I have been trying to generate. Whenever I add `-f config/project-scratch-def.json` to `sfdx force:package:version:create ...` it crashes.

Comment: I've very infrequently seen this happen due to SFDX caching an invalid org settings file. Try setting the environment variable `SFDX_MDAPI_TEMP_DIR` to something like `tmp` (in your current directory).

Comment: I do not think that could help because `SFDX_MDAPI_TEMP_DIR` is not even set as I just checked. Just to clarify I am not retrieving any settings file the only thing I am doing is using the scratch org definition file to create a package.

Comment: No, it usually won't be set. You can set it to make SFDX ignore whatever its default temp directory is, which (when I experienced a similar issue) was where the problem was located.

Comment: I have set it to a temp directory but it did not solve the problem unfortunately.

Comment: What helped me solve it, is by deleting the files at Local/Temp I am not sure of the reason for this but if anyone can explain what happens internally it would be nice.

Comment: I have spun up a fresh scratch org with the contents in your file and nothing else and it doesn't give any error 